# How do I mirror a Github repository using Web Hooks?

Tags: git, github, gitolite

I want to mirror a Github repo on my server using Web Hooks, or another real time mechanism. I don't want to use polling.

Is there any existing software? If not, how would you do it?

The server has `gitolite` installed.

Answer (score 1):

Gitolite is an [authorization mechanism](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html), which might not be involve if you get the new commits reference directly on the local repo server: your monitoring process could directly push said new commits to the local repo on that server, without having to use an ssh address controlled by gitolite.

If you activate a  [GitHub Post-Receive Hooks](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks), you could register your server httpd address, and listen for any POST with the new commits referenced in it.
When you receive such a post, you can `git fetch` and update your local bare repo on the server.